# I'm having trouble writing copy large files

Tags: java, base64

I'm having problems with my code, I'm encrypting a file with more than 300mb in base 64 but my application gives errors when I open the lra encrypt file

this is my code crashes on the byte, i don't understand why

```
private void encript(final File file) {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void[] p) {
            File new_file = null;
            try {
                new_file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".enc.txt");
                if (!new_file.exists()) {
                    new_file.createNewFile();
                }
                BufferedInputStream mInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                OutputStream mOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new_file));
                byte[] data = new byte[mInputStream.available()];
                int len = 0;
                
                while (true) {
                    len = mInputStream.read(data);
                    if (len > 0) {
                        mOutputStream.write(Base64.encode(data, 0, len, Base64.DEFAULT));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                mOutputStream.flush();
                if (mOutputStream != null) {
                    mOutputStream.close();
                }
                if (mInputStream != null) {
                    mInputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception io) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, io.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucesss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }.execute(new Void[0]);
    
}
```

Comment: How does it crash? What’s the actual error?

Comment: Please include the full error output in the question text

Comment: the application crashes out of nowhere when I open a large file

Comment: Out of nowhere, the OP ignores the above comments

Comment: It doesn't happen "out of nowhere" .  It (most likely) is reported as an exception that you are not handling *correctly*.  Change `catch (Exception io) {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, io.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}` to also log the exception.  And then show us the **complete** stacktrace.

Comment: Using `InputStream.available()` is the wrong thing to do. Also, base64 is not a form of encryption, and in addition, you seem to be encoding to base64 per `data` array you read, which means the file doesn't have a single base64 encoded content, it has multiple base64 encoded fragments, which likely cannot be decoded properly (because it might have base64 padding characters in the middle of the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that what you are doing here is Base64 encoding the file contents.  Don't imagine that someone can't trivially crack this (so-called) "encryption".

There are lots of things wrong with your attempt.  I shall go through the more important ones:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void[] p) {
        File new_file = null;
        try {
```

Problem: You should be using [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to avoid resource leaks.

```
            new_file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".enc.txt");
            if (!new_file.exists()) {
                new_file.createNewFile();
            }
```

Problems:

1. On the one hand, there is no need to use `createNewFile` to pre-create an output file.  Opening the file using `FileOutputStream` will create it if it doesn't exist already.
2. On the other hand, this won't prevent (or report) errors in cases where the file's parent directory doesn't exist, is not writeable and so on.
3. It would be better to use `java.nio.file.Path` and `java.nio.file.Files` from Java 7 / Android API 26. `Path` and `Files` are better APIs and they will report problems as exceptions so that you can (hypothetically) report them to the user via your exception handler.

   There are even some `Files.copy` methods, though they are not directly applicable to your use-case since you are encoding the data as you copy it.

   ```
            BufferedInputStream mInputStream = 
                new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            OutputStream mOutputStream = 
                new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new_file));
   ```

Problem:

I don't think you need a `DataOutputStream`.  It won't actually be doing anything.

```
            byte[] data = new byte[mInputStream.available()];
```

Problem:

The `available()` method should not be used for this.  It returns the number of bytes that are "available" to be read right now.  The value you get is context dependent.  For a socket stream it is typically the number of bytes that are currently in the kernel buffers ready to read.  For a "regular" file it may be the length of the input file.

So if you are copying a "really big" file, then you may be attempting to allocate a buffer that will hold the entire file.  In the worst case, that will cause your app to OOME!

**NOTE** - Such an OOME might be the "out of nowhere" problem that you are seeing.

The "best" way is debatable, but I would just use a fixed buffer size ... if I was doing an explicit read / write copy of a stream.  The size of the buffer affects throughput, but if you are looking for ultimate performance you shouldn't be doing it this way.

```
            int len = 0;
            
            while (true) {
                len = mInputStream.read(data);
                if (len > 0) {
                    mOutputStream.write(
                        Base64.encode(data, 0, len, Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
                break;
            }
```

Problem: This loop is simply wrong.  You are *unconditionally* breaking on the first iteration.  You should be doing something like this:

```
int len;
while ((len = mInputStream.read(data)) > 0) {
    mOutputStream.write(Base64.encode(data, 0, len, Base64.DEFAULT));
}
```

In other words, keep reading / writing until `read` returns a non-positive result.

Note: I'm not sure which `Base64` class you are using there.  It doesn't appear to be `java.util.Base64`

```
            mOutputStream.flush();
            if (mOutputStream != null) {
                mOutputStream.close();
            }
            if (mInputStream != null) {
                mInputStream.close();
            }
```

Problems:

1. The `flush()` is not necessary.  Closing the stream will flush.  And besides, what happens with your attempted flush if `mOutputStream` is `null`.
2. This version leaks resources (file descriptors).  If an exception has been thrown, these statements won't be executed, and the stream objects will not be closed.
3. This is all unnecessary if you use *try with resources* instead.

   ```
       } catch (Exception io) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, io.toString(),
                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

Problems:

1. Catching `Exception` is a bad idea.  A better idea is to catch and handle the *expected* exceptions, and let the unexpected ones propagate so that they can be handled further up the stack.

   In this case, it looks like you are assuming that the exception will be some sort of I/O exception.  In fact, it could also be an unchecked exception such as an NPE.  (An OOME is also possible, though this catch wouldn't catch that because OOMEs are `Error` exceptions.)
2. You are throwing away the exception details.  Unexpected exceptions should be logged so that you can diagnose them via logcat.

Comment: Likely the use `Base64.encode` is also problematic, I guess this might end up with base64 padding (`=`) in the middle of the file.